# Showing a Download link in WIX Condition Message

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have created a WIX Installer. One of the prerequisite for the Installer is that ASOLEDB(Microsoft Utility) should be Installed. I am able to find out whether ASOLEDB is Installed or not. If it is not present, I want to show a message to the user with a download link to download and Install ASOLEDB Manually. 
I have used the following condition:

```
<Condition Message="ASOLEDB is not installed.">IS_ASOLEDB_INSTALLED</Condition>
```

I am setting the property IS_ASOLEDB_INSTALLED in WIX, based on whether ASOLEDB is found or not.
Instead of showing the message "ASOLEDB is not installed." I want to show a complete message like "ASOLEDB is not installed. Please download and Install ASOLEDB from the following link:
"

When user clicks on the link, the web page is opened.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

LaunchConditions is not capable of displaying hyperlinks.  Windows Installer only recently added a hyperlink control in MSI 5.0 which means it's only possible in Windows 7 / Server 2008R2.

If this is really important to you, you'll have to write a custom action to display your own custom UI instead of using the Condition element.

Answer (score 0):

It Works for me on wix v3.11

```
<bal:Condition  Message="install KB00000 from &lt;a href=&quot;http://yahoo.com &quot;&gt;here&lt;/a&gt;.">
      CONDITION_VAR
</bal:Condition>
```

Comment: What version of Windows was this on? It does not seem to work in Windows 7 unfortunately.

Comment: It's win 7 sp1.